# Some parameters in CSS are ignored by Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I write this :
`.myform{     display:inline;     border: 1px;     color : blue; }`

in a custom css file in my Wordpress child theme , only the blue color appears on the screen.

I tried writing !important next to it but it still doesn't work and I can't figure out why those parameters aren't working

Comment: Have you had a look through you browsers dev tools to see what is overriding that CSS?

Comment: Yes I have checked that before , the properties are applied to my form  but they won't do anything to it. Also nothing seems to override my style.

Comment: I think we will need to see the site ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

try to inspect your element and add these css codes inside your Console, is that it the way you want your form to be displayed in?
secondly, you can use the !important to Force this css Code to be read

```
 .myform{     display:inline !important;     border: 1px !important;     color : blue !; }
```